# How can I set comparison datetime in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

If I console.log my datetime (`console.log(dateTime)`), the result is like this :

```
06-08-2017 16:05:00
```

It's a string. I want to compare the datetime with the current datetime + 5 hours. If my datetime <= current datetime + 5 hours then the message alert : failed

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try moment.js https://momentjs.com/docs/. It's very handy

```js
var date = moment("06-08-2017 16:05:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")
var now = moment().add(5, 'h');

//alert(now);

if (date < now) {
   alert('Fail');
} else {
   alert('Success');
}

//or

if (date.isBefore(now)) {
   alert('Fail');
} else {
   alert('Success');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can parse a string to date as follows:

```
var date = new Date("06-08-2017 16:05:00");
```

Then compare it with current time as follows:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var differenceInMiliseconds = currentDate - date;
var differenceInHours = differenceInMiliseconds/1000/60/60;
```

You could check the value of `differenceInHours`, and give an alert based on that.

Comment: `06-08-2017 16:05:00` = 6 August 3017. No 8 june 2017. If I `console.log(date)`, the result : 8 june 2017

Answer (score 0):

you can set current hour + 5 hours in a date object.

```
currentDateTime = new Date();
currentDateTime.setHours(currentDateTime.getHours() + 5)
if( dateTime <= currentDateTime){ //dateTime is your defined date object
    alert('Failed');
}
```